# Парсинг элементов раздела разбитого на несколько страниц

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom, интернет-магазин

Приветствую. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Имеется раздел на сайте с условными 1500 товарами, на странице отображаются по 25 товаров. Соответственно имеются кнопки навигации между первыми 25 товарами, вторыми и т.д. Проблема заключается в том, что кнопки не содержат явных ссылок на переход, и адрес страницы не меняется. Нужно программно получить html страниц со всеми элементами раздела.

Вот собственно говоря, как выглядит страница:
[image: Парсинг элементов раздела разбитого на несколько страниц]

URL: https://www.asbis.by/shop/pages/catalog.xhtml?catalogNode=SIMPLE%3D30

Парсер пишу на php + simple_html_dom + curl. Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: Смотрите в браузере какие сайт делает ajax запросы и просто повторите их

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполняйте POST запросы на https://www.asbis.by/shop/pages/catalog.xhtml

Offset и Limit указывайте в параметрах запроса

- pdtC:pdt_first:25
- pdtC:pdt_rows:25

Больше информации о передаваемых и получаемых данных вы найдете в Chrome DevTools